# Trignonometry application

Tags: trigonometry

How do I solve this question?
The angles of elevation of the top of a pole from three points A,B and C in a straight line(in the horizontal plane) through the foot of the pole are α, 2α and 3α respectively. If AB = a, then the height of the pole is :

1. a sin(α)
2. a sin(2α)
3. a tan(α)
4. a sin(3α)
   I think the figure of the problem must be this but I may be wrong:
   [image]

The correct answer is (2).

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: @LeeNeverGup height of the pole

Comment: @shauryagupta The correct answer is (2).

Comment: @shauryagupta ...but ...you ...just ...put the answer in the question...?

Comment: @DavidH My bad...My question is:How do i solve this?

Comment: Drawing a picture would be an excellent place to begin

Comment: @DavidH Picture drawn.

Comment: @shauryagupta Now recall the [Law of Sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines). Can you take it from there?

Comment: @DavidH I know only elementary trig, so this question needs to be solved without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call the foot of $h$ $D$ for the sake of clarity.  Since $a=\overline{AD}-\overline{BD}$, and $\tan{2\alpha}=\frac{h}{\overline{BD}}$, $\tan{\alpha}=\frac{h}{\overline{AD}}$, we can say
$$ \frac{h}{tan{\alpha}}-\frac{h}{\tan{2\alpha}}=a $$
By the tangent double angle formula, $\tan(\theta+\psi)=\frac{\tan{\theta}+\tan{\psi}}{1-\tan{\theta}\tan{\psi}}$.  It follows that 
$$\begin{align}
h\left(\frac{\tan{2\alpha}-\tan\alpha}{(\tan\alpha)(\tan{2\alpha})}\right)&=a \\
h\left(\frac{\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1-\tan^2\alpha}-\tan\alpha}{(\tan\alpha)\left(\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1-\tan^2\alpha}\right)}\right)&=a \\
h\left(\frac{\frac{2}{1-\tan^2\alpha}-1}{(\tan\alpha)\left(\frac{2}{1-\tan^2\alpha}\right)}\right)&=a \\
h\left(\frac{1+\frac{\tan^2\alpha-1}{2}}{\tan\alpha}\right)&=a \\
h\frac{\tan^2\alpha+1}{2\tan\alpha}&=a \\
h\frac{\sec^2\alpha}{2\tan\alpha}&=a \\
\frac{h}{2\sin\alpha \cos\alpha}&=a \\
h&=a\sin{2\alpha}
\end{align}$$